# Where did the "Not this shit again" bad sub meme originate from?

Tags: code-geass, meme

I have been seeing this meme all over the internet. Guessing from most of the Q&As I have found, this seems to be edited in. If so, what was the original verse and why did it get twisted in this way?

[image]

Comment: only general "bad subtitles" trvtropes entries exist, no exact match of this phrase on it

Comment: @HakashinouShinonouko Are you saying that the phrase was made up and the line didnt exist in this scene? If so, where is this scene from?

Comment: I'm saying I didn't find it on tvtropes and it's *the* place for memes to be, which you didn't say you searched.

Comment: @HakashinouShinonouko Ahh sorry, I misinterpreted you. Indeed I did not check there.

Comment: The screencap itself comes from the second OP of R2.

Comment: 2nd OP from 2nd season? I couldn't find this scene there. actually, I couldn't find this scene in any of the openings. But I really might be doing this wrong. XD

Answer (score 4):

At about 21:00 in Season 2 Episode 20, there's the same scene:

[image: Charles zi Britannia]

The plot:

> On the platform of the Sword of Akasha in the World of C, Charles zi Britannia is looking at the pillar-like object, telling the god that it's the time to finish everything. Lelouch then walks in saying that Charles is wrong.

I don't think the sub is related to the plot, but there may be one explanation:

"Not this shit again" might be one of Charles' inner thoughts when Lelouch walks in and interrupts him.